# Are questions about online translators on topic?

Tags: discussion

> I have a list of words that I want to convert to the roman alphabet,
>   mostly to be able to enter those from any English keyboard. For that
>   I'm using [this website](http://nihongo.j-talk.com) although I'm not
>   sure what's it retrieving when I choose any of the romanized alphabets
>   in the second selectable option to the right of the button that says
>   "translate now".

I this question on topic?

Comment: It seems very unlikely that this would be on topic... might be better to ask in the chatroom: https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/511/japanese-language